# Moving a rotated image using GestureDetector in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a following code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() {
  debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;
  return runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: TestComp(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestComp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestCompState createState() => _TestCompState();
}

class _TestCompState extends State<TestComp> {
  double _y = 0;
  double _x = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
          top: _y,
          left: _x,
          child: Transform.rotate(
            angle: math.pi / 180 * 90,
            child: Container(
              height: 200,
              width: 300,
              color: Colors.black,
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Positioned(
                    top: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onPanUpdate: (details) {
                        var dx = details.delta.dx;
                        var dy = details.delta.dy;
                        setState(() {
                          _y += dy;
                          _x += dx;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Image.network("https://via.placeholder.com/300x200"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Basically, the functionality is make the image draggable. But when I rotate it and try to move the image, the coordinates get messed up. It doesn't move in right direction. It works perfectly when the angle is 0. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you look into Draggable and  DragTarget widgets? If that helps on your usecase

Answer (score 1):

Flutter coordinate structure works slightly differently. I could not find a clear url for this, but in your case the values change as follows. You can try the code sample. To change the angle, you can assign another angle in the "map" into "selectedAngle".

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() {
  debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;
  return runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: TestComp(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestComp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestCompState createState() => _TestCompState();
}

class _TestCompState extends State<TestComp> {
  double _y = 0;
  double _x = 0;

  Map<int, double> map = {
    0: 0.0, // Same 360 angle
    90: math.pi / 180 * 90,
    180: math.pi / 180 * 180,
    270: math.pi / 180 * 270,
  };

  int selectedAngle = 270;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
          top: _y,
          left: _x,
          child: Transform.rotate(
            angle: map[selectedAngle],
            child: Container(
              height: 200,
              width: 300,
              color: Colors.black,
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Positioned(
                    top: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onPanUpdate: (details) {
                        var dx = details.delta.dx;
                        var dy = details.delta.dy;
                        var result = calculate(dx, dy);


                        setState(() {
                          _y += result['y'];
                          _x += result['x'];
                        });
                      },
                      child: Image.network("https://via.placeholder.com/300x200"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Map<String, double> calculate(double x, double y) {

    switch(selectedAngle) {

      case(0):
        return {'x': x, 'y': y};
        break;

      case(90):
        return {'x': -y, 'y': x};
        break;

      case(180):
        return {'x': -x, 'y': -y};
        break;

      case(270):
        return {'x': y, 'y': -x};
        break;

      default:
        return {'x': x, 'y': y};
        break;
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. The angle should be a double not int. So if I put like 136 it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can move down `Transform.rotate` to wrap `Image.network` 
see working demo below 
code snippet

```
 Transform.rotate(
                angle: math.pi / 180 * 90,
                child: Image.network(
                    "https://via.placeholder.com/300x200")),
          ),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() {
  debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;
  return runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: TestComp(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestComp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestCompState createState() => _TestCompState();
}

class _TestCompState extends State<TestComp> {
  double _y = 0;
  double _x = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
          top: _y,
          left: _x,
          child: Container(
            height: 200,
            width: 300,
            color: Colors.black,
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Positioned(
                  top: 0,
                  left: 0,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onPanUpdate: (details) {
                      var dx = details.delta.dx;
                      var dy = details.delta.dy;
                      setState(() {
                        _y += dy;
                        _x += dx;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Transform.rotate(
                        angle: math.pi / 180 * 90,
                        child: Image.network(
                            "https://via.placeholder.com/300x200")),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```